# ListView xml entries removed when new item added

Tags: android, xml, listview, adapter

I added items to a ListView using entries in the xml. But for some reason when I dynamically add items to the ListView the entry items get removed.

Can someone please explain why?

Code:

list_view_fragment.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ListView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:entries="@array/listview_array"
    android:id="@+id/listview1">
</ListView>
```

ListViewFragment.java

```
public class ListViewFragment1 extends Fragment {

    protected ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
            @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {       

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_fragment, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.items);     
    }

    public void changeText(String data){
        ListView list1 = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        list1.setAdapter(adapter1);
        adapter1.add(data);
        adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }   
}
```

I think when I dynamically add items using `changeText(String data)` I create a new `ListView` that removes all the entries from the xml.

Can someone please help? -- How do I save my entries?

Comment: where is changeText called from ?
If you have more entries you should probably use a "holder"...
Also you can think of creating ListView in onActivityCreated and just add and notify adapter...

Comment: it's called from the MainActivity. But it's the code inside changeText that's causing the error.

Comment: also when I add these two lines into onActivityCreated:         ListView list1 = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview1);
        list1.setAdapter(adapter1); - my original entries don't even load

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
public void changeText(String data){
    ListView list1 = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    list1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    adapter1.add(data);
    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

to this

```
public void changeText(String data){
    adapter1.add(data);
    adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

And change your `onCreateView` to

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
        @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState){       

    adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.items);  
    ListView list1 = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listview1);
    list1.setAdapter(adapter1); 
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_fragment, container, false);
}
```

Code not tested. Let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: my original entries don't even load when I do that. Strange. --- The entries which should appear from this source:  android:entries="@array/listview_array" ---- It's as if a new ListView is created and deletes my old ListView

Comment: Might have something to do with you defining the entries in XML. Can you add them dynamically? @user2456977

Comment: I definitely can, but I just want to know why I can't add dynamically and also through xml

Comment: @user2456977 Try my edit. Moved code to `onCreateView` from `onActivityCreated`

Comment: If that still doesn't work, try chaning `getActivity()` to `container`

Comment: nope...runtime error. does not work in onCreateView. And what do you mean by changing getActivity() to container, how do I do that?

Comment: In your onCreateView method, when you fetch your list view, change getActivity() to container. @user2456977